# Problem with deleting a photo object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have this in my view,

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
  <%= link_to "Destroy", photo, :method => "delete" %>
<% end %>
```

And I get an **undefined method `photo_path'** error.

I'm using paperclip.

And here's the extract from my rake routes.

```
DELETE /admin/issues/:issue_id/photos/:id(.:format) {:action=>"destroy",controller=>"admin/photos"}
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
  map.resources :issues, :has_many => [:notes, :photos]

  map.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.resources :issues 
    admin.resources :issues do |issue|
      issue.resources :photos
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you mapped :photo as a resource in your routes.rb?

---

**UPDATE**

Based on your routes, maybe this would work:

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
  <%= link_to "Destroy", admin_issue_photo_path(photo), :method => "delete" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I've updated the answer, hopefully it works (admin_issue_photo_path).

Comment: Thank you so much. A variant of your answer worked. <%= link_to "Destroy", admin_issue_photo_url(:id => photo.id), :method => "delete" %>